# Find all fucntions $f(x)$ that satisfy: $|f'(x)|\le2014|f(x)|$, $f'(x)$ continuous on R and $f(x)=0$

Tags: real-analysis, functions

Find all fucntions $f(x)$ that satisfy that $f'(x)$ continuous on $\mathbb{R}$, $f(x)=0$ and
$$\left| {f'(x)} \right| \le 2014\left| {f(x)} \right|,\forall x \in \mathbb{R}.$$
I have no idea where to start. Please give me a hint, thank you!

Comment: Are you sure about the condition $f(x)=0$?

Comment: Hint: try some simple differentiable functions with $f(x) = 0$. Do they satisfy the inequality? Why or why not? Can you use this to characterize all functions satisfying your requirements?

Comment: @JuliánAguirre Yes, I'm sure about that!

Comment: Well then  $f(x)=0$ for all $x\in\Bbb R$. There is only one such function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: If $|f'| \leq c\cdot |f|$ for some constant $c$, and $f$ is $0$ at some point, can $f$ ever "escape" from $0$?

Try applying Rolle's theorem to the interval between a point where $f=0$, and any "sufficiently close" point where $f\neq 0$.